traveling to the US with J-1 and ESTA at the same time
I am traveling to the US for a research internship for 1 month with a J-1 visa, then I am supposed to be going to another city for a Medical clinical elective for which the ESTA would be the appropriate way to enter the US (as a B1-B2 waiver). The clinical elective and my flight home would anyway be less than 30 days after the end of my J-1 program. Is it possible for me to enter the US with my J-1 and the ESTA at the same time and stay for these 2 months?

You have a 30-day grace period after the end of your J1 program. Do you know if your clinical elective would be an acceptable activity during a J1 grace period?

Hi, thank you for your answer! What are the requisites for an acceptable activity under a J1 grace period? I will be basically in a hospital following a doctor doing a "clerkship" , but I won't be paid or anything (you actually have to pay to attend, and they say an ESTA is enough to go there)

@user102008 sorry I forgot to tag you!


Is it possible for me to enter the US with my J-1 and the ESTA at the same time?

No.
But basically anything that is permissible as a VWP visitor is permissible in the J-1 grace period.
